# Alarme com mal funcionamento

Tags: android

Boa tarde, estou com problemas em relação ao AlarmManager no meu projeto, eu programei para ele fazer uma ação das 10 as 11, e das 16 as 17 com intervalos de 1 dia.
Então o problema é que no outro dia ele não esta alarmando, já fiz vários testes com intervalos mais curtos e funcionaram, também fiz o mesmo teste com intervalo de 1 dia altarando a data e hora do aparelho manualmente , e funcionou! Mas quando tento normalmente, fico esperando no dia seguinte alarmar, mas não funciona.Eu creio que é a estrutura que esta errada pois usei o AlarmManager dentro de uma classe Service, então segue minhas classes do projeto:

```
public class AlarmService  extends Service{


    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();

    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        alarm();
        stopSelf();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    }

    /*
     * Metodo para gerenciar os alarmes
     */
    public void alarm() {
        try{
        //Variáveis referente a minuto e segundo, fazendo um random
        Random min = new Random();
        Random sec = new Random();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min.nextInt(60));
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, sec.nextInt(60));

        Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
        calendar2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min.nextInt(60));
        calendar2.set(Calendar.SECOND, sec.nextInt(60));


        Intent tarefaIntent = new Intent(AlarmService.this, NotificacaoReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent tarefaPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                AlarmService.this, 0, tarefaIntent, 0);

        Intent tarefaIntent2 = new Intent(AlarmService.this, NotificacaoReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent tarefaPendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                AlarmService.this, 1, tarefaIntent2, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) AlarmService.this
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Define o alarme com intervalos de 1 dia
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                tarefaPendingIntent);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar2.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                tarefaPendingIntent2);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("FadireAlarme", e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Lembrando que o alarme é chamado quando inicia a aplicação, ou da o boot no dispositivo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagino que você já tenha lido a documentação oficial, mas de qualquer maneira vou deixar o link de um guia como referência: [Scheduling Repeating Alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

Sendo assim, a primeira observação que faço, seria ao invés de utilizar Random pra variar os minutos e segundos, utilizar o método [setInexactRepeating()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) (ao invés do setRepeating), assim você permite que o Android agrupe os alarmes próximos e economize bateria.

O correto é utilizar um BroadcastReceiver como base para o AlarmManager. Caso você esteja usando um receiver e então disparando algum Service (Context.startService()) para executar a tarefa, é provável que o dispositivo esteja dormindo antes de completar a tarefa. Então, como diz na documentação oficial, você irá precisar de uma nova regra de wake lock separada para evitar que isso aconteça.

Isso não deve ter acontecido em outros momentos, pois você talvez estivesse com o dispositivo conectado ao seu computador ou esperando acontecer alguma coisa, e com isso o device não entrava em sleep mode.

Para isso, adicione a permissão no seu Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

E no seu receiver, antes de chamar o service faça assim:

```
WakefulIntentService.acquireStaticLock(context);
context.startService(new Intent(context, SuaClasseServiceQueExecutaTarefa.class));
```

Depois no Service, não esqueça de tratar o wake lock.
Não encontrei um exemplo em português, tem esse post em inglês que é bem completo: [Using IntentService With AlarmManager to Schedule Alarms](http://dhimitraq.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/using-intentservice-with-alarmmanager-to-schedule-alarms/)

Além disso, quando você faz:

> Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

O correto é logo na sequência adicionar:

```
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: Eu não estou ultilizando nenhum broadcastReceiver para chamar o alarmService, eu chamo direto pela atividade.Será esse o problema?

Comment: @WarLock sim, é necessário registrar o receiver. No link que passei no começo da resposta tem um exemplo completo de como usar e registrar alarmes. Dê uma olhada, e qualquer coisa posso ajudar editando minha resposta.